# Firebug displaying some Socket.IO requests in red others in black

Tags: socket.io, firebug

The same URL is displayed in red sometimes while in other times black.  I can't see a difference between the two requests.  Does anyone know why?

The versions I use are:

- Firebug 2.0.17b1
- Firefox 43.0.1
- Socket.IO 1.4.5
- Node.js 6.3.0

The server-side code is rather simple:

```
var http = require('http')
var _server = http.createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(_server);

// QUESTION: I still get CORS errors although I have these allowed origins:
io.set('origins', "ws://localhost:* ws://127.0.0.1:* http://localhost:* http://127.0.0.1:*");

_server.listen(63143);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("EventServer: connection");

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log("EventServer: disconnect");
    });
});

var url = require('url');
_server.on('request', function (req, res) {
    console.log('EventServer: client request: ' + req.url);

    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    //res.write('OK');  <========= QUESTION: this throws 'write after end' exception. Why?
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Please add a screenshot of Firebug's *Net* panel, so people can see what you see. Is the issue only related to Firebug or can you also reproduce it in the Firefox and Chrome DevTools? Also, Firefox 43.0 is outdated. The current version is 47.0.1.

Comment: How add an image?  No image button and docs give URL examples, which I have no server to host an image.

Comment: There *is* an image button. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/252674 for an explanation.

Comment: I don't get that with "Add Comment".  Only a text area and an "Add Comment" button beside it.

Comment: You need to edit your question to add the image, not add a comment.